# Extract the first four words from a sentence

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, substring, worksheet-function

Given a sentence, for example:

> The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog

what Excel formula would extract the first four words?:

> The quick brown fox

Comment: Have you tried a simple search? I've got about 531,000 results in  0.36 seconds. Your starting point is: LEFT().

Comment: Yes I have tried that, they usually talk about getting the first or last or nth word but nothing about extracting a specific number of words, in my case the first 4 words.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried so far. We'll take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","|",4),FIND("|",(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","|",4)))-1)
```